# Can you halt processing from within an action if the posted data is too large?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an action in a controller that processes a JSON payload in my API.

This JSON payload can sometimes get too large and I don't want to process the request if it is above some threshold, let's say 1 megabyte.

If the JSON is 100 megabytes, am I forced to wait for the entire JSON to be loaded into memory or can I shortcircuit the process and just return a Forbidden Response by streaming the body and calculating the size, and once it goes over my threshold I can halt/return and not waste my server resources by loading the entire 100 MB into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BodyParser` can do this for you. By default, Play's `BodyParser`s will only accept 100KB of data before returning a 413 error (request entity too large).

You can override this, by setting the `BodyParser` for a single `Action` to allow a max length that can be buffered in memory. `parse.maxLength` can transform a `BodyParser[A]` into a `BodyParser[Either[MaxSizeExceeded, A]]`.

In this case, we want `BodyParser[Either[MaxSizeExceeded, JsValue]]`.

```
def process() = Action(parse.maxLength(1024 * 1024, parse.json)) { request =>
    request.body.fold(
         maxExceeded => EntityTooLarge("Your request must be smaller than 1MB!"),
         json => // .. do something with JSON
    )
}
```

Or, if you want to set this application wide, there are configuration options that allow this:

**Play 2.0.x - 2.3.x**:

```
parsers.json.maxLength = 1m
```

**Play 2.4.x**:

```
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer = 1m
```

[Play Documentation - Body Parsers - Max content length](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Max-content-length)

Comment: This assumes you have a request body that must be parsed (like for the OP). If you are streaming the request body and handling it manually, you can always count the bytes and abort if needed. I won't go into that here, as that's a more case-by-case thing.

Comment: Is this the most efficient way?  I'm guessing under the covers it is also streaming and if it goes over it stops i.e. it can't really parse until the entire payload has finished streaming and is within the threshold.